# Instantiating an Inheritance Object Class with Parent Properties

Tags: c#

I am using an SDK method that returns a model native to that SDK.

In my code, I want to add some extra properties to my base class.

Example:

```
public class BaseClass {
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
} 

public class ChildClass : BaseClass {
   public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}


BaseeClass baseClassObject = SDK.Method1();

ChildClass child = new ChildClass(); <- Populate this with baseClassOjbect properties.
```

Is inheritance the best to do this/most efficient? If so, how do I instantiate the child object with the properties of the base class?

I could create a new class without inheritance with the properties of the BaseClass and then some extra properties (without using inheritance) but I just wonder if there's a 'better' use of C# for achieving this?

Comment: Check out composite design pattern

Comment: Could do it with a copy constructor, maybe?

Comment: I wouldn't directly inherit from a class that I have no control over. Might as well create my own class, and map that to the SDK object. Or as @Nkosi hinted, use composition over inheritance.

Comment: @ragyaiddo This was actually my original plan, but I just wanted to see if there was a more appropriate "C# Way" of doing this.

Comment: @Nkosi Composition is normally what I go with when designing this. I've decided to do this instead! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider passing the base object to the child and copy the desired properties

```
public class BaseClass {
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
} 

public class ChildClass : BaseClass {

    public ChildClass() : base() {}

    public ChildClass(BaseClass baseClassObject) : base() {
        this.Prop1 = baseClassObject.Prop1;
    }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

So now the child class can be initialized like this

```
BaseeClass baseClassObject = SDK.Method1();

ChildClass child = new ChildClass(baseClassObject) {
                        Prop2 = "Some value"
                   };
```

and get populated with `baseClassOjbect` properties.

Comment: Thank you for the example. This design patterns works the way I need it to!